# MST with possibly minimal diameter

Tags: graphs, trees, minimum-spanning-tree, spanning-trees

I am working with some research problem connected loosely to TSP which requires to find the Minimum Spanning Tree of a fully connected, weighted graph, where all the weights are positive and the graph is undirected (just like in Christofides algorithm). The point is, the problem I am working on requires me to find the MST with possibly lowest diameter (the number of nodes on the longest path between any two leaf nodes, equivalently, for the purpose of measuring the diameter one can treat all the edges of the MST as if they had the weight equal to 1).

I know that Boruvka's, Prim's and Kruskal's algorithm can be used to find some MST, but can I influence them somehow to prefer the shortest (in the terms of the diameter) trees possible?

If the answer to the question above is negative, are there any algorithms or methods which either yield MST with some bounds on the tree diameter or, at least, are there any known methods of obtaining a bound on MST diameter for a given graph?

Comment: Yes, my bad. The diameter (or width) of a tree is the number of nodes on the longest path between any two leaf nodes - that is exactly the parameter I want to minimize.

Comment: Do you need it to be minimum weight, breaking ties by minimum diameter?  Is this a weighted or unweighted graph?   For purposes of measuring the weight of a spanning tree, you take into account edge weights, but for purposes of measuring diameter, you treat all edges as length 1?  Or something else?  It might help to state each of these aspects a bit more clearly in the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is necessary that the weight of the tree is minimal, so the search for the minimum diameter is performed within the set of all Minimum Spanning Trees for the given graph. Thanks for your comment, I hope I clarified some of the understatements You've mentioned.

Comment: A partial answer to your last questions: there is no good bound on the diameter of the MST vs the diameter of the original graph. Think of a path on $n$ nodes in which each edge has weight 1, and complete it by adding all the missing edges with weight $1+\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. The diameter of this graph (w.r.t. the hop-distance) is $1$ (and $1+\varepsilon$ if we take weights into account). The unique MST has diameter $n$.

Comment: If you are fine with having a spanning tree that weighs at most $O(1)$ times the weight of a MST and has a diameter that is at most $O(1)$ times the (weighted) diameter of your graph, then you can build a [light approximate shortest path tree](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01294129) rooted in a center of the graph.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a problem of more theoretic nature, therefore minimal weight is a must have. Nevertheless, I see now that I cannot expect any reasonable estimates on MST diameter (the graphs I am working with have no additional assumptions except for the ones I listed out in the question). Thank You!